# Chromedriver does not respond on Centos 7

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, centos7, google-chrome-headless

Hi in a headless `centos 7` I am trying to getting work headless selenium tests.
To do that I Installed google-chrome, chromedriver and selenium pip package but I have no success here is what I have done.

google-chrome version:

```
yum list installed |grep google-chrome
google-chrome-stable.x86_64             83.0.4103.106-1                @google-chrome
```

I downloaded chrome driver version `83.0.4103.39` from this [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/), unzip it and move it to the `/usr/bin/local`

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 10774816 May  5 23:53 chromedriver
```

and that path is in env as well.

```
PATH=...:/usr/local/bin/chromedriver:/usr/local/bin/
```

When I type chromdriver in the terminal nothing happens. It just stucks. I am behind corporate proxy so I can't really try to change firewall or etc. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? If not, when you try to exit, do you get any messages/warnings? You could be receiving a timeout error but not having it shown. Is there any more information you could share for me to help? Websites often detect automation.

Comment: I am actually just trying to write `chromedriver` and make sure its working by seeing its version but it shows me no output. It just waits

Answer (score 0):

Don't put binary executables on `$PATH`, but only directory `/usr/local/bin`.

You'll have to source the profile after editing it: `. ~/.bashrc`.

And you might have to configure it for headless mode:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--incognito');
```

Also check for possible alerts there: `sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`.